# Flutter setState not updating variable inside ExpansionPanelList

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a filter that update the selected option like the image using a ExpansionPanelList, something like this...

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TKXw.jpg)

In my code I'm trying to update a subtitle Text from a property returned from the body of the same ListTile Widget which contain the RadioListTile Widget inside of ExpansionPanel Widget inside of ExpansionPanelList Widget.

The value I want is from another StatefulWidget class where the RadioListTile works perfectly, and the value is returned by a Callback to the class I need to use this variable named _orderByOptionSelected, but the variable I'm using is not updated even inside of the setState method.

Here is the class that contains the RadioListTile selection:

```
class ElementFilterOrderBy extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElementFilterOrderBy({Key? key, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);
  static const String best = 'best';
  static const String reviews = 'reviews';
  static const String price = 'price';
  static const String location = 'location';

  final Function(String) onChanged;

  @override
  State<ElementFilterOrderBy> createState() => _ElementFilterOrderByState();
}

class _ElementFilterOrderByState extends State<ElementFilterOrderBy> {
  String _orderBySelection = ElementFilterOrderBy.best;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        RadioListTile<String>(
          title: const Text(ElementFilterOrderBy.best),
          value: ElementFilterOrderBy.best,
          groupValue: _orderBySelection,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _orderBySelection = value!;
              widget.onChanged(_orderBySelection);
            });
          },
          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        RadioListTile<String>(
          title: const Text(ElementFilterOrderBy.reviews),
          value: ElementFilterOrderBy.reviews,
          groupValue: _orderBySelection,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _orderBySelection = value!;
              widget.onChanged(_orderBySelection);
            });
          },
          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        RadioListTile<String>(
          title: const Text(ElementFilterOrderBy.price),
          value: ElementFilterOrderBy.price,
          groupValue: _orderBySelection,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _orderBySelection = value!;
              widget.onChanged(_orderBySelection);
            });
          },
          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        RadioListTile<String>(
          title: const Text(ElementFilterOrderBy.location),
          value: ElementFilterOrderBy.location,
          groupValue: _orderBySelection,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _orderBySelection = value!;
              widget.onChanged(_orderBySelection);
            });
          },
          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my class where I'm trying to update the value returned:

```
class CustomBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomBottomSheet> createState() => _CustomBottomSheetState();
}

class _CustomBottomSheetState extends State<CustomBottomSheet> {
  late String _orderByOptionSelected;
  late String _searchLocation;
  late List<ItemExpansionPanel> _optionsFilter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _orderByOptionSelected = 'best';
    _searchLocation = 'Actual Location';

    _optionsFilter = [
      ItemExpansionPanel(
        headerValue: kFilterOptionOrderBy,
        widgetBody: ElementFilterOrderBy(
          onChanged: (selectedOption) {
            setState(() {
              _orderByOptionSelected = selectedOption;
            });
          },
        ),
        optionSelected: _orderByOptionSelected,
      ),
      ItemExpansionPanel(
        headerValue: kFilterOptionLocation,
        widgetBody: Container(),
        optionSelected: _searchLocation,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kPaddingApp),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text(
            kFilterTitle,
            style: kTextStyleBoldBlackBig,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: kMarginApp,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: _buildPanel(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _optionsFilter[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _optionsFilter.map<ExpansionPanel>((ItemExpansionPanel item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
              subtitle: Text(
                item.optionSelected,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: kAccentColor,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          body: item.widgetBody,
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class ItemExpansionPanel {
  ItemExpansionPanel({
    required this.headerValue,
    required this.widgetBody,
    required this.optionSelected,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  final Widget widgetBody;
  final String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
  String optionSelected;
}
```

Edit 1: Added more elements on the list to only change the ItemExpansionPanel selected

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_orderByOptionSelected` as text value not `item.optionSelected`.

go to `CustomBottomSheet` then `_buildPanel()` widget then change it to this.

```
Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _optionsFilter[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _optionsFilter.map<ExpansionPanel>((ItemExpansionPanel item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
              subtitle: Text(
                _orderByOptionSelected,
                // item.optionSelected, <== DELETE This
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          body: item.widgetBody,
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But If I have more elements on my list _optionsFilter this will change all the values, I only need to change the ItemExpansionPanel used

Comment: add more elements on your list, edit the question with new code and i will edit your code to work as you wish.

Comment: Thanks man, I updated the code with another element

Comment: add `ElementFilterLocation()` code to

Comment: `ElementFilterLocation()` is class that only contains an empty `Container()` widget just to show the example with the _optionsFilter list with more elements